# trying to use actionbarSherlock in tab activity

Tags: android, android-tabhost, actionbarsherlock

I want to have an actionBar at top and, tabs on the next row.

My activity extended TabActivity, and used getActionBar();

Now I'm trying to use getSupportedActionBar() of sherlock and having touble.

> When creating an activity to use the action bar on all versions of
>   Android, you must declare your activity to extend any of the activity
>   classes that start with 'Sherlock' (e.g., SherlockActivity,
>   SherlockFragmentActivity). Interaction with the action bar is handled
>   by calling getSupportActionBar() (instead of getActionBar()).

How do I use sherlock and tabActivity at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13640512/741249

Answer (score 1):

There are examples of using tabs with ActionBarSherlock in the samples included with the project.

Check out the [FragmentTabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java) and [FragmentTabsPager](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabsPager.java) examples.

Short answer is you extend SherlockActivity and then declare the TabHost programmatically.