# Android Actionbar Sherlock with Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, android-tabs

[image]

I am trying to implement ActionBar Sherlock with Tabs below that as shown in the above wire-frame.

Should i use TabActivity ? - since i saw that it is deprecated. Which is the best way to achieve the same.

Comment: can you share the answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I implemented this functionality with a `SherlockFragmentActivity` as tabview container and with `SherlockFragment` as tabs. Here is a sketch (I omitted the usual Android activity stuff):

This is the tabview activity with two tabs:

```
public class TabViewActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
  // store the active tab here
  public static String ACTIVE_TAB = "activeTab";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ..
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    // add the first tab which is an instance of TabFragment1
    Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab()
              .setText("TabTitle1")
              .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabFragment1>(
               this, "tab1", TabFragment1.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab1);

    // add the second tab which is an instance of TabFragment2
    Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab()
           .setText("TabTitle2")
           .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabFragment2>(
                this, "tab2", TabFragment2.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);

    // check if there is a saved state to select active tab
    if( savedInstanceState != null ){
      getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                  savedInstanceState.getInt(ACTIVE_TAB));
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // save active tab
    outState.putInt(ACTIVE_TAB,
            getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
}
```

And this is the `TabFragment` that holds a tab's content:

```
public class TabFragment extends SherlockFragment {
  // your member variables here
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_va_esh, container, false);
    ... // do your view initialization here
    return view;
  }

}
```

And finally this is the `TabListener` that handles tab switches:

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener{
  private TabFragment mFragment;
  private final Activity mActivity;
  private final String mTag;
  private final Class<T> mClass;

  public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mTag = tag;
    mClass = clz;
  }

  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
    if (mFragment == null) {
      // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
      mFragment = (TabFragment) Fragment.instantiate(
                        mActivity, mClass.getName());
      mFragment.setProviderId(mTag); // id for event provider
      ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
    } else {
      // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
      ft.attach(mFragment);
    }

  }

  public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if (mFragment != null) {
      // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
      ft.detach(mFragment);
    }
  }

  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
  }
}
```

Comment: How can we add share button at action bar to harsha mv 's question.?

Comment: @suresh: This is a different issue. See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10278952/620338).

Comment: @MattHandy i want to add Tabs as well as ActionBar Iteams. so will ur solution work ?

Comment: This will work. The tab view will appear right below your action bar.

Comment: @MattHandy:I am getting error at this line, telling to create a new ActionBar class  :::::                                               public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener

Comment: You need the TabListener from my third snippet. Otherwise, please tell more about your error.

Comment: TabListener<T extends Fragment>. does type parameter extends Fragment from android support library or maybe SherlockFragment?or maybe simple Fragment?

Comment: @grine4ka: It's android.support.v4.app.Fragment in my case

Comment: hey... my tabs didn't comes under the action bar.

Comment: hey can u pls add the layout for TabFragment.

Comment: what is  "mFragment.setProviderId(mTag);"

Comment: @Vikky: This is a member variable of TabFragment. It is specific to my project and is probably not necessary for you

Comment: I have created a github project based on this example. I hope it helps. https://github.com/jiahaoliuliu/ActionBarSherlockTabs

Answer (score 4):

I believe TabActivity is deprecated in favor of using Fragments -- not because tab navigation is a deprecated concept.  Simply use Fragments and a TabWidget.

Also, here's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599816/creating-tabs-using-fragments-now-that-tabactivity-is-deprecated).

Edit:

Here's an example courtesy of Google: [Android Tabs the Fragment Way](http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/04/android-tabs-the-fragment-way/)