# remove blue lining in android application layout

Tags: android, layout

I cant remove the blue line present in my android application that is found available in the snapshot ,aht the mouse points at.
Please tell me how can i remove it...

I am using action bar sherlock and fragment both in the app.So I used a Theme.Sherlock

Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ur_layout);

Comment: but Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE gives me a nullpointer exception when I use getSupportActionBar()

Answer (score 0):

It seems something you missed in use of  sherlock  library  and once you are using that lib you dont need to apply theme to your xml file ,

you have not past your code so it would difficult to say what went wrong . here i can find the  one answers related to your question  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13640827/501483

Comment: no not writing anything in my project.
just edited one line in the sherlock library's style xml file.
made the theme.noactionbar change to ....fullscreen 
.but the blue line does not relate to that work.
it was appearing before that step also.
i had to edit the sherlock library to remove space of the application name title that was appearing when the app was launching for the first time

Comment: it seems not the problem with theme , use that link i have provided