# How to add data or activity to tab in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-tabs

[See My previous question (Linked here)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18079274/2576034) . I am with answer but now i want to add data to tabs by intent activity or any other procedure how to add widgets or any other resources because when i intent any other class its show in all the other tabs also. How to get different activity in different tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your stuff in tab host and make linear layout or Relative Layout for your each  tabs (below frame layout).

Comment: had you go through my link? i have added tabs progmatically because i am using actionsherlockbar so am not getting it this way!